# filter for multiple record based on latest timestamp

Tags: django-models, django-datatable

I have the following table:

```
Record    Created         Name    Group
1         July 23, 2015   John    Group 1
2         July 21, 2015   April   Group 1
3         April 4, 2015   John    Group 1
```

How do you filter for the latest distinct record? In this example, I would expect to get record 1 and 3?  My code:

```
Model.objects.filter(Group='Group 1').latest('Created')
```

only grabs record 1.

Answer (score 0):

`latest` return an object (row) that is, well, "latest" based on specified field provided as argument.
If you need several records (rows) then you need to get a QuerySet.
Try:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(Group='Group 1').order_by('-Created')[:2]
```

this should give you rows 1 and 3 as you expect.